# NSException raise:format: as the last statement in a method

Tags: objective-c, exception, nsexception

I have this method:

```
+ (MHTwitterParser*)createParser:(NSString*)format {
    if ([format compare:@"json"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        return [[MHJsonTwitterParser alloc] init];
    }

    [NSException raise:@"Unknown format" format:@"Unknown format of parser"];
}
```

Compiler complains that:

```
Control may reach end of non-void function
```

It is just a warning, but it does not matter.

Obvious fix for that is to add for example `return nil;` after the `[NSException raise: ...`.

However, I think it is not needed (and is even misleading for readers), because the exception is thrown, so it is not true that "Control may reach end of non-void function". Or am I missing something ...? Is it only compiler imperfection or there is some considerable reason for this?

The compiler is Apple LLVM compiler 3.1

Comment: It's just a method on an object, if I wanted I could swizzle the method to not throw an exception and then my program would reach the end of non-void function... I'm sure there are other more usable reasons

Comment: @Paul.s Thanks Paul. That makes sense and it is valid point. I am curious if somebody will come up with some other explanation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is simple.

For the compiler, the method `[NSException raise: ...]` is a black box method. It doesn't know that the method will actually raise an exception.

If you compare it with Java or C++, their `throw` statements are a language feature and the compiler knows exactly what will happen when it finds it. In Obj-C it's different and sometimes it depends on runtime conditions. Consider the following.

```
NSException* exception = nil;

if (someCondition) {

   exception = [NSException exceptionWithName:...];
}

[exception raise];
```

The compiler won't know if the exception is really raised or not.

Comment: The explanation is really nice, but this is not the accurate answer. The warning is not because compiler doesn't recognizes `NSException` but it can see a non-returning statement at the last line, just after a condition (which may be executed or may not)

Comment: @geekay That's not true. If you replace the last statement with something the compiler undestands, e.g. `abort()` or `assert(false)`, you won't get a warning. The issue here is that the compiler doesn't know that raising a `NSException` will interrupt program flow.

Comment: @sulthan, thanks man, I need to dig into that more now. But I have faced this warning even without `NSException` scenario

Answer (score 12):

Replacing `[exception raise];` with `@throw exception;` is functionally the same thing and will prevent the warning (see: [Throwing Exceptions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/RaisingExceptions.html)).

Answer (score 1):

The warning is there simply because not every path through the code ends with a return statement which the compiler recognizes as potentially problematic. That said, you probably shouldn't be throwing an exception here and should instead be generating an `NSError` and returning `nil`. The differences between exceptions and errors in objective-c are explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Exceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000012i) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806).

Comment: right, it has nothing to do with `NSException` and this warning would've occurred even if there were any other (non-return) statement as a last statement.