# Any reason -[NSException raise] does not have noreturn attribute?

Tags: objective-c, clang, nsexception

I am writing a custom assertion macro. It call this function when assertion failed.

```
void _XLCAssertionFailedCritical(NSString *format, ...) __attribute__((noreturn));
void _XLCAssertionFailedCritical(NSString *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);

    NSException *ex = [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInternalInconsistencyException reason:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:ap] userInfo:nil];

    va_end(ap);

    [ex raise];
}
```

but it have a warning

> XLCAssertion.m:69:1: Function declared 'noreturn' should not return

change `[ex raise]` to `@throw ex` fixed the warning.

But the warning won't exist if `-[NSException raise]` have `noreturn` attribute. In fact, none of the methods in `NSException` have `noreturn` attribute.

I understand that `[ex raise]` may still return if ex is `nil`. In this case, `noreturn` attribute shouldn't be allowed on instance method at all. But `[NSException raise:format:]` always raise an exception (unless someone swizzled it...) so `noreturn` should be used to help compiler analyze unreachable code and check method does not return.

This just make me think that `raise` and its family on `NSException` should never be used. But I can't find documentation/guide about that. Did I missed something?

Comment: One workaround is [Jeffery Thomas's answer to "+\[NSException raise:format:\] as the last statement in a method"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10401916/603977): use `@throw` instead. Since this is a compiler directive, the analyzer knows that it is terminal.